# Need help with equation $y''(x)-y'(x)tgx+2y(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with equation $y''(x)-y'(x)tgx+2y(x)=0$ and $y(0)=1,y'(0)=1$

We can guess solution $y_1(x)=\sin x$ and assume that second solution is $y_2(x)=z(x)\sin x$. To find $z(x)$ we have to put our assumed solution into equation.
Putting into equation and multiplying by $\cos x$ we get:
$$
\sin x\cos x\cdot z''(x)+(2\cos^2x-\sin^2x)z'(x)=0
$$
We can substitute $z'=g$ and obtain after little work:
$$\frac{dg}{g}=\frac{\sin^2x-\cos^2x}{\sin x\cos x}dx$$
Now there is assumption in work that $\sin x\neq0$, so $x\neq0$. Therefore we won't find anything useful for solution which is defined in $0$. So do we need to carry on with that way, or we can just safely assume that $\sin x=0$ and have $$2z'(x)=0$$ therefore $z=const$ so solution which work is $y=\sin x +1$?
Do I need to worry about uniqueness of this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $z'=0$ leads back to the family $y=C\sin x$ of solutions that you already know. $y=1$ and thus also $y=\sin x+1$ are not solutions of the equation.

You lost a factor of $2$ while transforming.

The integration of the correct identity should lead to
$$
z'=\frac{C}{\sin^2x\cos x}=\frac{C\cos x}{\sin^2x(1-\sin^2x)}.
$$

As you have a linear ODE, uniqueness of the solutions follows from the continuity of the coefficients. $\tan x$ is continuous on a neighborhood of $x=0$.

Comment: I see, but if $z'=\frac{C}{\sin^2x\cos x}$ then $z=\frac{1}{2}(\ln (\sin x+1)-\ln (\sin x+1))-\frac{1}{\sin x}$, which is not defined for $x=0$, so it seems that only solution in $0$ have form $y=C\sin x\neq1$. So where can I find proper solution?

Comment: You still need to multiply with $\sin x$, the resulting function is defined at $x=0$.

Comment: but what about derivative? Part of it is $z'\cdot\sin x$, which is not defined in $0$. Same with $z\cdot\cos x$

Comment: But the resulting function is defined in $x=0$ and also is a solution there. Of course you have to be careful with singularities of intermediary results, but in the end what counts is that the form of the solution has been found.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have obtained satisfies the initial conditions so it is indeed unique.

Comment: Not a critique, but a question: is that actually sufficient to guarantee uniqueness? I suppose it is, but it seems awfully simple.

Comment: Uniqueness follows from the continuity of the coefficient functions, as the equation is linear. Thus any function that actually solves the ODE and satisfies the initial conditions is a solution to the ODE.